# System.PlatformNotSupportedException when trying to read a JPEG image in C# in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.mac

How can I read a JPEG file into the memory in C# using Visual Studio for Mac?

My code:

```
using AppKit;
using Foundation;

namespace TouristFree
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate : NSApplicationDelegate
    {
        public AppDelegate()
        {
        }

        public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
        {
            var filename = "/Users/person/Desktop/image.jpeg";
            var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename);   // <— error here
        }
    }
}
```

Throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException.

Answer (score 0):

To load images outside of the application's bundle (from the Mac file system):

```
NSImage image = new NSImage("/Users/person/Desktop/image.jpeg")
```

re: [Using images in C# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/app-fundamentals/image#using-images-in-c-code) (Xamarin.Mac)

Comment: Very good resource, thanks! I confirm that the code works. However, how can I convert NSImage into System.Drawing.Image so that I can share my code between Windows and Mac? My ultimate goal it to convert the image into a byte-array of RGB(A) pixels.

Comment: @adamsfamily Since you are not looking to display that image, you might want to look at NetStd2/NetCore: System.Drawing.Common  https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common